# Saving a different file output after rendering?

Tags: rendering

Is it possible to save a file output after rendering that wasn't previously set up in the node editor when rendered?

For example if I rendered a scene with all of the passes send to an .exr but then wanted to just render the combined image to a png. When the scene was rendered only the export to .exr was set up and the .png wasn't. Is there any way to do this without rendering again?

Comment: Yes there is, you can use the *File Output* node in the compositor for this

Comment: How do you save the file from the File Output node after it is connected with the passes you want to export?

Comment: When I connected the .exr it output it automatically but if I add another file output node after rendering is there a way to still export the file from the file output node afterwards without rendering?

Comment: I don't have a lot of practical experience with the node, see the [Blender Manual - File Output Node](https://www.blender.org/manual/compositing/types/output/file.html) for more info

Comment: No need to re-render. Import that rendered EXR and plug the channel(s) you want to save to a file output node to create a png file.